# If a light socket only has 2 connections, how can they sell 3 prong light socket adapters?

Tags: ground, socket

If a light socket only has 2 connections (thus not grounded) then how can they sell 3 prong (grounded) light socket adapters? How is this legal and safe? If it's grounded, then how does that work? e.g. Amazon's Choice in Light Sockets: [https://www.amazon.com/Socket-Adapter-Polarized-Splitter-Converter/dp/B09R1H8FHN/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09R1H8FHN)

Or "better" yet, one that claims to be **UL and FCC listed!** [https://www.amazon.com/Socket-Adapter-Listed-Polarized-Converter/dp/B0B433M3HN](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0B433M3HN)

How does the ground work exactly?

[image]

Comment: There will be some weasel words in fine print somewhere.

Comment: Might as well ask how they can sell these: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07MTPDNMV/

Comment: Yes, but that product has a 3rd lead for you to connect the ground wire, so by itself it's not illegal, is it? It depends if you connect the ground lead or not.

Comment: I don't see a UL logo.  And then there's this monstrosity (Ask your local poco about the advantages of backfed systems /s): https://getwiredusa.com/ols/products/generator-back-feed-the-house-l14-30p-4-pin-generator-male-plug-to-14-30p-4-pin-male-plug-power-cord-adapter-l14-30p-14-30p-fx510c

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen This one claims to be UL and FCC listed! https://www.amazon.com/Socket-Adapter-Listed-Polarized-Converter/dp/B0B433M3HN

Comment: @that-ben - that's called lies (or marketing). I don't see the UL logo in any of their product photos, nor is the listing number mentioned anywhere in their lies (or marketing). Then apply a little critical thinking - why would a dumb passthrough power device even need FCC listing or approval?

Comment: Wow, that should be marketed as “how to kill a lineman”

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The seller is in China. They can sell and deliver anything you want to buy, even if a product is dangerous or fake. They are not guaranteed to comply with any local safety regulations and have not been tested for such regulations. They just make it available, and it's your problem if you buy it.

In some jurisditions, you are allowed to buy dangerous products and use them, but then you are also the importer of the product and you as the importer are responsible for the safety of the imported product. May affect how insurance deals with it, if the product you imported yourself burns down your house, as you have no one you can claim responsible.

If in doubt, don't buy.

Comment: And Amazon, an U.S. giant company, can sell this to North Americans legally and even advertise this product as an Amazon's Choice?

Comment: @that-ben "Sold by Danceonship".  They'll argue they're not selling anything if you take them to court.  Amazon's business model is that they're essentially eBay connecting buyers and sellers, so its your own fault if you buy something dangerous.  Courts are starting to see through that argument, but not enough to stop them so far, at least in the USA.

Comment: Both fascinating and concerning.

Comment: @that-ben unless the Amazon listing specifically states that the product is "Sold By: Amazon", then they'll say that they're just the warehouse & logistics for the foreign seller.